# How to close file resources in pyglet

Tags: python-3.x, pyglet

This is definitely a repeat of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31975061/how-to-unload-close-resources-in-pyglet), but seeing as how that has gotten 0 replies in 3 months, and I can't seem to find an answer. The question ought to be simple: once you're done with a file (say, a video or a sound) in pyglet, how do you go about closing that file? I have an application which has to iterate over a few hundred thousand files, processing each one in turn. For obvious reasons, I am getting `OSError: Too many open files`. Is there a way to force-close pyglet's files?

Comment: Can you explain a little more about your project? What kind of resources are you loading and why such a large number at once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For sound or video files you can close the current source with the [Player delete() method](http://pyglet.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/pyglet/media/player/pyglet.media.player.Player.html#pyglet.media.player.Player.delete).

You can also load the resource directly into memory instead of streaming from disk by setting the streaming argument to false in the load call:

`pyglet.media.load(filename, streaming=False)`

If all else fails, try forcing the garbage collector with `python.gc.collect()`.

Comment: the `delete()` method seemed to do nothing, but `streaming=False` works great. It's not a slowdown because I have to read most or all of the file anyway. your `python.gc.collect()` made me think of using python's built-in `del` command, and that worked OK too.